# Coefficients of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, coefficients

Let's say I have the polynomial $x+2y+3xy \in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ or $x_1+2x_2+3x_1x_2 \in \mathbb Q[x_1,x_2]$, that is `x+2y+3xy` or `x[1]+2x[2]+3x[1]x[2]`. Is there a simple command to get all the coefficients at once, that is `{1,2,3}`?

So far, the following works for the latter case (based on the ordering of `MonomialList`), but is there perhaps a more intuitive way?

`MonomialList[x[1]+2x[2]+3x[1]x[2]] /. x[i_Integer] -> 1`

`MonomialList[x[1]+2x[2]+3x[1]x[2]] /. _x -> 1`

**Edit**: I've found a method (based on the ordering of `CoefficientRules`) that can be used for both cases. It seems that this is the easiest way.

`Values@CoefficientRules[x+2y+3xy]`

`Values@CoefficientRules[x[1]+2x[2]+3x[1]x[2]]`

Comment: `CoefficientList` will provide the matrix of all of the coefficients. With this list you could reproduce the polynomial.

Comment: No, `CoefficientList[x+2y+3xy]` doesn't work.

Comment: `CoefficientList[x + 2 y + 3 x y, {x, y}]` does

Comment: But that doesn't yield three elements like `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: If you interpret the output of what Bob advices correctly, you get your 1,2,3

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` seems ambiguous, or do the powers & order not matter? That `x + 2 y + 3 x y` and `x + 3 x y + 2 x^2` are both `{1, 2, 3}` in some order?

Comment: I'm interested only in the rational coefficients, so in both polynomials you have given they are essentially `{1,2,3}` (up to ordering).

Comment: Then `Values@CoefficientRules[..]` seems easiest.

Comment: You could post it as a self-answer. Also `Union@Values@CoefficientList[..]` would sort the results and delete duplicates, in case you want to treat the coefficients as a **set**.

Comment: You mean `Union@Values@CoefficientRules[..]`, right?

Comment: Oops, yep. (User @MichaelE2 to make sure I get notified.)

Answer (score 3):

One can apply

`Values@CoefficientRules@p`

to a given polynomial `p` to get its coefficients (according to the ordering of `CoefficientRules`).

Answer (score 1):

Two more suggestions. I have taken the comments into consideration.

The test cases are:

```
poly1 = x + 2 y + 3 x y;
poly2 = x[1] + 2 x[2] + 3 x[1] x[2];
poly3 = x + 3 x y + 2 x^2;
```

First solution

```
foo[function_] := Cases[function, x_. y___ :> x, {1}]
```

and then

```
foo[poly1]
foo[poly2]
foo[poly3]
```

to get

> [image: 123]

Second solution

```
foo[function_] := 
 Sort[Numerator[(List @@ (function /. 
       Thread[Variables[function] -> 1/Variables[function]]))]]
```

and then

```
foo[poly1]
foo[poly2]
foo[poly3]
```

to get

> [image: 123]